# conda - calling python file with specific environment

Tags: php, python, conda

I am building an app which running backend with `php` and required to call functions from `python`.
I know I can call `python` functions from `php` by using `exec()`.

But, my `python` functions is running under specific `conda` environment which, packages were installed specifically for the environment.

How can I make sure the `python` is running at specific environment when I call it from `php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is to run your Python script with the Python interpreter from the specific environment you want to use, e.g. (on Windows):

```
C:\path\to\conda\env\python.exe myscript.py
```

If that doesn't work, write a batch file or shell script that first `activate`s your chosen env, then runs the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i've done in my PHP script in order to run it both on the development server (on Windows) and the production server on Linux :

```
if (preg_match ("/win32|win64/i", $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'])) {
  $cmd = "call conda.bat activate && set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && python myscript.py";
}
else {
  $cmd = "export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 && python3 myscript.py";
}
```

Adapt this example according to your installation (path to python script, conda environment name if not the "base" environment, etc.).
https://rc-docs.northeastern.edu/en/latest/software/conda.html