# Executing conda command in php using shell_exec()

Tags: python, php, anaconda, conda, shell-exec

$activate1 = shell_exec('conda --version 2>&1');
echo $activate1;

'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Above is the error I am getting although I have set path to conda in my environment but i am unable to execute conda commands using shell_exec() in php. I am using windows 10 and sublime text editor and visual studio code. Someone please help.

Comment: Did you tried to put the command into a batch file? shell_exec("your_script.bat");

Comment: just tried it..it still isnt working

Comment: It worked when I restarted my computer

Comment: See my answer to the quite same question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55093969/conda-calling-python-file-with-specific-environment/68918919#68918919